# Is it possible to add a custom 15 inch device in firebase test lab

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

We have integrated our application with Firebase test lab for testing. But we need to test the flow in 15 inch device, is there an option in Firebase test lab to add custom device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Test Lab only tests against devices that are hosted in a Google data center, or virtual devices.  It's not possible to change the set of devices there.  If you're interested in adding a virtual device configuration, please [contact Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).